# Numpy Create 3D Array from 1D Array by Repeating Original Element into 2nd/3rd Axis

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose we have a `(n x 1)` boolean array, i.e.

```
array([True, False, True, True])
```

how can we generate a `(n x 2 x 3)` array where all values in the 2nd and 3rd axis have the same values as the element in first axis that it was repeated from?

```
array([
    [[True, True, True], 
     [True, True, True]], 

    [[False, False, False], 
     [False, False, False]],

    [[True, True, True], 
     [True, True, True]], 

    [[True, True, True], 
     [True, True, True]]
])
```

The resulting boolean array is meant to be used as a mask to select data in a `(n x 2 x 3)` array, where the first axis represents the sample index, and the 1D array decides which samples we want to select all its `(2 x 3)` data from.

In other words, if an element is `True` in the original 1D array, replace it by a `(2 x 3)` array of `True`s:

```
array(
    [[True, True, True],
     [True, True, True]]
)
```

Comment: Technically, the shape of your first array is `(n,)`, not `(n, 1)`.

Comment: `np.broadcast_to(x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis], (x.size, 2, 3))`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Works, thanks!